# Rails collection_select, wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a collection_select to assign a branch_id to a visit (in a form where a user books a visit with a branch) but I'm getting the error "wrong number of arguments (7 for 4..6)".

I've been using the documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select And as far as I can see, my code matches the example.

Here is my collection_select:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :branch_id, "Please Pick Service Provider/Branch you would like to visit:" %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:visit, :branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :branch_name_select, {prompt: "Select the Branch/Service"}, {:required => true}) %>
</div>
```

branch.rb:

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :visits

 def branch_name_select
   "#{branch_name}, #{address_line_1}, #{address_line_2}, #{city}, #{postcode}"
 end

end
```

visit.rb:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :branch  
    belongs_to :user #:as => 'created_by' 
    validates_uniqueness_of :time_from, :scope => [:date_from, :location], :message=>"slot is already taken on selected date"

end
```

Comment: Post your full form code.

Comment: Try this `<%= f.collection_select(:branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :branch_name_select, {prompt: "Select the Branch/Service"}, {:required => true}) %>`

Comment: Thanks very much Pavan, that fixed it and the correct branch id is now saving. If you want to post this as an answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
<%= f.collection_select(:visit, :branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :branch_name_select, {prompt: "Select the Branch/Service"}, {:required => true}) %>
```

should be

```
<%= f.collection_select(:branch_id, Branch.all, :id, :branch_name_select, {prompt: "Select the Branch/Service"}, {:required => true}) %>
```